# Execute SQL for different where clause from Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to print SQL result through python code, where I an trying to pass different predicates of the where clause from a for loop. But the code only taking the last value from the loop and giving the result.

In the below example I have two distinct id values 'aaa' and 'bbb'. There are 4 records for id value = 'aaa' and 2 records for the id value = 'bbb'.
But the below code only giving me the result for the id value ='bbb' not for id value 'aaa'

Can anyone help to identify what exactly wrong I am doing?

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="user1", passwd="pass1", db="db1")

cur = db.cursor()

in_lst=['aaa', 'bbb']

for i in in_lst:
    Sql = "SELECT id, val, typ FROM test123 Where id='{inpt}'".format(inpt=i)

print(Sql)
cur.execute(Sql)

records = cur.fetchall()
print(records)

db.close()
```

The result I am getting as below

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/Koushik/PycharmProjects/Test20161204/20170405.py
SELECT id, val, typ FROM test123 Where id='bbb'
(('bbb', 5, '1a'), ('bbb', 17, '1d'))

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="1234", db="sakila")

cur = db.cursor()

in_lst=['1', '2']

for i in in_lst:
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM actor Where actor_id='{inpt}'".format(inpt=i)
    print(Sql)
    cur.execute(Sql)
    records = cur.fetchall()
    print(records)

db.close()
```

Indentation is your problem, please update the code according to your needs...

Comment: Yes, it was indentation only. It's very strange in Python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Within your `for` loop, you're formatting the sql statement to replace "{inpt}" with "aaa". However, before you do anything with that value, you're immediately overwriting it with the "bbb" version.

You would need to either:

1. Store the results somehow before the next iteration of the loop, then process them outside of the loop.
2. Process the results within the loop.

Something like the following will give you a list containing both results from the fetchall() calls:

```py
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="user1", passwd="pass1", db="db1")

cur = db.cursor()

in_lst=['aaa', 'bbb']
records = list()
for i in in_lst:
    Sql = "SELECT id, val, typ FROM test123 Where id='{inpt}'".format(inpt=i)

    print(Sql)
    cur.execute(Sql)

    records.append(cur.fetchall())
print(records)

db.close()
```

Comment: No it is still not returning the value for aaa. It seems to me that somehow for loop unable to recognize that it is multi line for loop. It is executing like a single like for loop, so the print statement is not printing the sql for id=aaa. How can I write a for loop in python which will be multiple line (like for C we can give {})